# Create oracle apex theme with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, oracle-apex

I'm trying to build a custom theme for oracle apex 4.0 with bootstrap.
But I have some issues with some templates like login, reports
I am modifying the theme No. 18 (simplified grey) and don't look good
Anybody knows some references to create the theme.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex.nl has a free bootstrap 3.0 theme for Oracle Apex.

"As of now a first beta version of the theme is available. The (stable) version 2.0 of the theme is expected to be released at Kscope14. "

http://apex.nl/apex/f?p=125:2:11114570464128:ITEM:::P2_NSIM_ID:10902

Comment: I try this theme but when I try to import the theme there is a error. I think that theme is generated in APEX 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Joseleg,

For creating Bootstrap theme refer blog

[Front-end frameworks in Oracle APEX](http://apexplained.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/front-end-frameworks-in-oracle-apex/)

download bootstrap demo application (download link at bottom), install in your workspace and try to create theme by taking reference theme created in demo application.

Comment: I download the sql file to export the theme, but I dont know what next after the immport

Comment: this application contains Bootstrap theme.  so go to theme and refer theme template how they created that themes and then try to create your own theme.